# Reading and retrieving data from all rows for a coloumn on parse.com databse for android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have 4 rows of data saved for a column called **Message** on Parse.com database.

[image]

How can I read all the rows and store data in a string array on android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much straight from [the doc](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-basic-queries):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClassName");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i=0; i<objects.length; ++i) {
                Log.d("tag", "message=" + objects[i].getString("Message"));
            }
        }
    }
});
```